# Evariste Galois' proof of the "Primitive Element Theorem"

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, math-history

I've been reading Galois' memoir on the insolvability of the quintic and am trying to understand his reasoning on a lemma which seems to be a version of the primitive element theorem.

In modern language, he supposes $K$ is a number field, $a,b, c, ...$ is a finite collection of algebraic numbers, and $V = \varphi(a,b,c,...)$ is a rational function of $a,b,c,...$ for which

$$\varphi(\sigma(a),\sigma(b),\sigma(c),...) \neq \varphi(a,b,c,...) $$

for any permutation $\sigma$ of $a,b,c,...$.  Then, Galois claims that $K(V) = K(a,b,c,...)$.

For example, if $V = \sqrt{2} + 2 \sqrt{3}$, then this says that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ both are polynomial functions of $V$.

I'm not able to follow his reasoning (I will supply a picture of the text soon).  He says to look at the product

$$F(V,a) = \prod\limits_{\sigma} (V - \varphi(a,\sigma(b),\sigma(c), ...)) = 0.$$

as $\sigma$ runs through all permutations of $b,c,...$.  This product is symmetric in $b, c, d, ...$, so Galois says we should just think of this equation as a function of $V$ and $a$.  He then says "we can pull $a$ out of the equation."  What does this mean, and why does it follow that $a$ (and likewise, $b, c,$ etc.) can be solved for as a rational expression in $V$?

Comment: It seems like you must have misunderstood something: it is definitely not true that $K(V)$ has to be all of $K(a,b,c,\dots)$ under the hypotheses you have written.  For instance, if $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$, you could have just $\varphi(a,b)=a$ and then the two permutations are different, but $\mathbb{Q}(V)$ is just $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  Or more drastically, you could have $\varphi(a,b)=a^2$ and then $\mathbb{Q}(V)$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$!

Comment: I would guess for the intended statement, $a,b,c,\dots$ should be *all* the roots of some polynomial $g$ over $K$.  Then the point is $a$ is the *only* common root of the polynomial $h(x)=F(V,x)$ and $g$ and so by the Euclidean algorithm you can write $x-a$ as a $K(V)[x]$-linear combination of $h$ and $g$.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578323/primitive-of-a-splitting-field-obtained-from-galois-resolvent) for more details (and in particular my answer for some subtleties in exactly how the polynomial $F$ should be defined).